# Python remove or replace key

Tags: python

I'm trying to get rid of the value **Name** in a response. See below:

```
response_data_all_details = decode_transaction_response(response.text)

# Remove and sensitive information we don't want to be stored in the database.
response_data = remove_sensitive(response_data_all_details)
```

**Function: If there is name in the response replace it with "Not Stored" Text.**

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    for key in data:
        if data[key] == "Name":
            data['Name'] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

However, this function does not appear to work, why?

**Sample response_data**

```
{
  "URL" : "http:\/\/www.test.com",
  "Name" : "James",
  "Currency" : "GBP",
  "Amount" : 5.880000000000001,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution here is to use:  `if key in data`

```
def remove_sensitive(data,key):
    if key in data:
         data[key] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

**Fixing your code:**

You have to use `if key == "Name":`:

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    for key in data:
        if key == "Name":
            data[key] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

That's because an iteration over a dictionary yields it's keys one by one:

```
>>> for key in data:
...     print key
...     
URL
Currency
Amount
Name
```

demo:

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    for key in data:
        if key == "Name":
            data[key] = "Not Stored!"
    return data

>>> data = {                   
  "URL" : "http:\/\/www.test.com",
  "Name" : "James",
  "Currency" : "GBP",
  "Amount" : 5.880000000000001,
}
>>> remove_sensitive(data)
{'URL': 'http:\\/\\/www.test.com',
 'Currency': 'GBP',
 'Amount': 5.880000000000001,
 'Name': 'Not Stored!'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You made it too complicated. This should work:

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    data['Name'] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

or, if you are not certain the key `'Name'` is there:

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    if data.has_key('Name'):
        data['Name'] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    for key,value in data.items():
        if key == "Name":
            data[key] = "Not Stored!"
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize the dict method `has_key()`

```
def remove_sensitive(data):
    if data.has_key("Name"):
        data["Name"] = "Not Stored"
    return data
```